# how to use python to calculate the percentage of the dark area of a noise image

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

Here I uploaded a image which is very noisy.
and in the image there are some dark areas.
is there a way to use python to do image processing and calculate the percentage of the dark area?

[noise x-ray image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wcO0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact requirement so let me formalize a little bit what I understood from the limited description in the question:

**Required:**

For some grayscale image `img`, we want to calculate as a percentage of the total number of pixels, the number of pixels that have an intensity value below a certain threshold, say *t*

Assuming you have loaded your image into a numpy array, you can simply calculate the total number of pixels with intensity value < *t* and divide by the total number of pixels.

```
num_dark_px    = sum(img[img < t])
num_total_px   = img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]
dark_area_pcnt = num_dark_px / num_total_px
```

If there is another objective, please specify more information about the problem.

Comment: Thanks! sorry that I didn't make it clear. in the image I provided, there are some area is darker than the rest of the area. and because the image is noise, your method will count a lot of pixels which in fact not belong to the darker area. so I would like to ask if there is a method to identify those darker area and then calculate the percentage.

Comment: I am not familiar with which kind of technique will help denoising this medical image, knowledge of the type/source of noise helps in deciding this. But, you could start by trying something simple like 'smooth' the image using Gaussian Filters and then following the same approach of counting 'dark' pixels. This would give a crude estimate of what I understand you are looking for. A more sophisticated approach could include something like denoising/smoothing followed by connected components and then evaluating the percentage dark pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Gaussian filter helps, then set a clamp limit, above certain value to set pixel to 1 and below to 0, and then it roughly can calculate the percentage

Comment: This is a naive approach, and you can explore more sophisticated methods if this approach does not cut it for you.